# route missed in kubernetes with calico

Tags: kubernetes, networking, calico

I am installing k8s with calico on centos8, everything looks well but I couldn't ping each other between pods.

I am using k8s as DATASTORE of calico, the deployment file is in [calico.yaml](https://github.com/k8s-installer/k8s-installer/blob/master/ansible/roles/network-plugin/calico/templates/calico.yaml.j2)

I don't know why there are some route missed, any suggestions are appreciated.

Here are some informations about the cluster:

```
# kubectl get nodes
NAME                  STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
instance-4njec0xa-1   Ready    <none>   3h55m   v1.19.4
instance-4njec0xa-2   Ready    <none>   3h55m   v1.19.4
instance-4njec0xa-3   Ready    master   3h56m   v1.19.4
```

on master node

```
# ./calicoctl node status
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |    INFO     |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| 192.168.0.194 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 04:10:41 | Established |
| 192.168.0.195 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 04:10:41 | Established |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 192.168.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.17.139.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali96f39d92828
172.17.139.128  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
172.17.139.129  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 caliccf893b1917
172.17.139.130  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali09dc1beebda
172.17.153.64   192.168.0.194   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.181.64   192.168.0.195   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

on node1

```
# ./calicoctl node status
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |    INFO     |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| 192.168.0.195 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 04:10:42 | Established |
| 192.168.0.196 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 04:10:40 | Established |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 192.168.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.17.139.128  192.168.0.196   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.153.64   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
172.17.153.69   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali2587d39bec8
172.17.181.64   192.168.0.195   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

on node2

```
./calicoctl node status
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |    INFO     |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+
| 192.168.0.194 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 04:10:42 | Established |
| 192.168.0.196 | node-to-node mesh | up    | 04:10:40 | Established |
+---------------+-------------------+-------+----------+-------------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 192.168.0.2     255.255.255.255 UGH   100    0        0 eth0
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.17.139.128  192.168.0.196   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.153.64   192.168.0.194   255.255.255.192 UG    0      0        0 eth0
172.17.181.64   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.192 U     0      0        0 *
172.17.181.66   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali12d4a061371
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
```

Comment: Doesn't the `pods-network-cidr` overlap with the IP range of your VMs ?
Is it possible for you to share your exact `pod-network-cidr` and `service-cidr` ?
Do you have any additional cluster configuration e.g. k8s network policy, calico network policy ?
Did you follow official docs about installing and configuration k8s with `rhel 8`? 
Did you disable `SELinux` ?
Do you meet these [requirements](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/#before-you-begin) ?

Comment: There are no overlap. I fixed this problem. It's because I disabled IPIP and vxlan. When I set ipip to "always", everything works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calico [file](https://github.com/k8s-installer/k8s-installer/blob/master/ansible/roles/network-plugin/calico/templates/calico.yaml.j2) default disable ipip and vxlan, which causes the network failure. When I enable ipip and set the correct veth_mtu everything works well.

Answer (score 0):

I have situation like this
I had 3 worker nodes with calico (without any changes)
My cluster spinning up in openstack and workers payload cant communicate with each other over IPIP. *I create network rule in openstack which allow TCP #4 traffic between nodes*. After a few seconds my cluster started working great again